# Unable to deserialize the execution context after upgrading to spring boot 2.0 for a spring cloud dataflow task

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I updated my spring boot (Task) application to spring boot 2.0 from 1.5. Now when I run it I get a deserializable error.

```
2018-10-29 15:03:00.346 ERROR 713 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mediaiq.miq.batch.MiqBatchApplication.main(MiqBatchApplication.java:42) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [aiq-miq-batch-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [aiq-miq-batch-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [aiq-miq-batch-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [aiq-miq-batch-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:202) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:83) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.getJobExecutions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:264) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id '' as a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: no such class found
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["map"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1635) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1187) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:44) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar!/:2.9.7]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:70) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:322) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.1.RELEASE]
```

One person had suggested that :
This error happens when the execution context of your job is serialized with version 3 (using XStream by default) and then deserialized with version 4 (using Jackson by default). So either downgrade Spring Batch to version 3 or configure your job repository to use the XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.

In your case, you have already defined a bean of type BatchConfigurer, so you can override the createJobRepository method and configure the XStream serializer. For example:

```
@Bean
BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.setSerializer(new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

I added the above bean to my main class but still got the error.

Comment: Please add your full configuration for us to be able to determine what's going on.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

In the `batch_job_execution_context` table, you may have some records which are created by the spring batch version 3. While you are trying to execute new execution with spring batch version 4, it trying to compare previous records. So it trying to deserialize those older records. this is why you are getting this issue.

Spring batch version 3 records are like bellow in the `batch_job_execution_context` table

> {"map":[{"entry":{"string":["key","value"]}}]}

Spring batch version 4 records are like bellow in the `batch_job_execution_context` table

```
{"key":"value"}
```

Remove all the records created by version 3. This will fix the issue.

Comment: I cleared all Job executions and the issue is still present. Also, I didn't change the version of the Spring Batch either.

Comment: this bug still exists in the last versions, i had it today. In my case I moved a class from a package to another, and I had to delete the records of the table batch_step_execution_context referencing that class, because when i launched the job jackson was complaining about the non-existence of that class. That in fact no longer existed in the package referenced by scdf. @TomasLukac did you check both tables?